# How should I implement Guava cache when I plan to cache multiple values efficiently?

Tags: java, caching, guava

I have a Java class that has a Guava `LoadingCache<String, Integer>` and in that cache, I'm planning to store two things: the average time active employees have worked for the day and their efficiency. I am caching these values because it would be expensive to compute every time a request comes in. Also, the contents of the cache will be refreshed (`refreshAfterWrite`) every minute.

I was thinking of using a `CacheLoader` for this situation, however, its load method only loads one value per key. In my `CacheLoader`, I was planning to do something like:

```
private Service service = new Service();

public Integer load(String key) throws Exception {
    if (key.equals("employeeAvg"))
        return calculateEmployeeAvg(service.getAllEmployees());

    if (key.equals("employeeEff"))
        return calculateEmployeeEff(service.getAllEmployees());

    return -1;
}
```

For me, I find this very inefficient since in order to load both values, I have to invoke `service.getAllEmployees()` twice because, correct me if I'm wrong, `CacheLoader`'s should be stateless.

Which made me think to use the `LoadingCache.put(key, value)` method so I can just create a utility method that invokes `service.getAllEmployees()` once and calculate the values on the fly. However, if I do use `LoadingCache.put()`, I won't have the `refreshAfterWrite` feature since it's dependent on a cache loader.

How do I make this more efficient?

Comment: You may want to consider using a [materialized view](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Materialized_view) instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like your problem stems from using strings to represent value types (Effective Java Item 50).  Instead, consider defining a proper value type that stores this data, and use a [memoizing `Supplier`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Suppliers.html#memoize-com.google.common.base.Supplier-) to avoid recomputing them.

```
public static class EmployeeStatistics {
  private final int average;
  private final int efficiency;
  // constructor, getters and setters
}

Supplier<EmployeeStatistics> statistics = Suppliers.memoize(
    new Supplier<EmployeeStatistics>() {
  @Override
  public EmployeeStatistics get() {
    List<Employee> employees = new Service().getAllEmployees();
    return new EmployeeStatistics(
        calculateEmployeeAvg(employees),
        calculateEmployeeEff(employees));
  }});
```

You could even move these calculation methods inside `EmployeeStatistics` and simply pass in all employees to the constructor and let it compute the appropriate data.

---

If you need to configure your caching behavior more than `Suppliers.memoize()` or [`Suppliers.memoizeWithExpiration()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Suppliers.html#memoizeWithExpiration-com.google.common.base.Supplier-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) can provide, consider this similar pattern, which hides the fact that you're using a `Cache` inside a `Supplier`:

```
Supplier<EmployeeStatistics> statistics = new Supplier<EmployeeStatistics>() {
  private final Object key = new Object();
  private final LoadingCache<Object, EmployeeStatistics> cache =
      CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
        // configure your builder
        .build(
           new CacheLoader<Object, EmployeeStatistics>() {
             public EmployeeStatistics load(Object key) {
               // same behavior as the Supplier above
             }});

  @Override
  public EmployeeStatistics get() {
    return cache.get(key);
  }};
```

Comment: Seems like `Supplier#get` recalculates the value every time the method is invoked. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: No, the `Suppliers.memoize()` decorator caches the value of the wrapped supplier, so it's only computed once.  If you use `Suppliers.memoizeWithExpiration()` it will be processed only once per time limit.  Or, if you use the other pattern I suggested, you can define more powerful caching behavior, at the expense of a slightly more complicated `Supplier`.

Comment: Seems like `Suppliers.memoizeWithExpiration()` is the one that I need! Thank you for this!

Comment: Happy to help :)  Suppliers are really useful (arguably more useful than caches, for day-to-day use cases).  They're a good thing to get used to working with.

Comment: Follow-up question, in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31575598/guava-how-does-cacheloader-load-work/31575654#31575654 I found out that I didn't need to synchronize `CachedLoader.load()` anymore. My question is, is `Supplier.get()` thread-safe?

Comment: By default `Supplier.get()` is not (after all, it just calls the method as you defined it).  *But* [the supplier returned by `Suppliers.memoize()` is thread-safe](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/master/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Suppliers.html#memoize%28com.google.common.base.Supplier%29).  Since `.get()` is a method you define, you could define it in a thread-safe way, as well.

Comment: There is also [`Suppliers.synchronizedSupplier()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/master/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Suppliers.html#synchronizedSupplier%28com.google.common.base.Supplier%29) which is likely what you'd usually want out of a thread-safe supplier.

Answer (score 2):

> However, if I do use `LoadingCache.put()`, I won't have the `refreshAfterWrite` feature since it's dependent on a cache loader.

I'm not sure, but you might be able to call it from inside the `load` method. I mean, compute the requested value as you do and `put` in the other. However, this feels hacky.

If `service.getAllEmployees` is expensive, then you could cache it. If both `calculateEmployeeAvg` and `calculateEmployeeEff` are cheap, then recompute them when needed. Otherwise, it looks like you could use two caches.

I guess, a method computing both values at once could be a reasonable solution. Create a tiny Pair-like class aggregating them and use it as the cache value. There'll be a single key only.

---

Concerning your own solution, it could be as trivial as

```
class EmployeeStatsCache {
    private long validUntil;
    private List<Employee> employeeList;
    private Integer employeeAvg;
    private Integer employeeEff;

    private boolean isValid() {
        return System.currentTimeMillis() <= validUntil;
    }

    private synchronized List<Employee> getEmployeeList() {
        if (!isValid || employeeList==null) {
            employeeList = service.getAllEmployees();
            validUntil = System.currentTimeMillis() + VALIDITY_MILLIS;
        }
        return employeeList;
    }

    public synchronized int getEmployeeAvg() {
        if (!isValid || employeeAvg==null) {
             employeeAvg = calculateEmployeeAvg(getEmployeeList());
        }
        return employeeAvg;
    }

    public synchronized int getEmployeeEff() {
        if (!isValid || employeeAvg==null) {
             employeeAvg = calculateEmployeeEff(getEmployeeList());
        }
        return employeeAvg;
    }
}
```

Instead of `synchronized` methods you may want to synchronize on a private final field. There are other possibilities (e.g. `Atomic*`), but the basic design is probably simpler than adapting Guava's `Cache`.

---

Now, I see that there's `Suppliers#memoizeWithExpiration` in Guava. That's probably even simpler.

Comment: I was actually thinking of just using a single key and caching a JSON'ed version of the object

Comment: @MiguelPortugal If all you need is the JSON'ed version, then OK, but otherwise a trivial immutable two-member class is much better.

Comment: Is it advisable to use Guava cache for instances like these? It seems like Guava cache is meant for storing multiple objects like a `LoadingCache<Integer, Employee>` where the Integer value is an ID and its value is a corresponding employee

Comment: @MiguelPortugal That's surely true. If there's just one element, then you don't need it. You just have to implement the loading and expiration yourself, which sounds pretty simple. +++ But this also holds for your original 2-element cache and that's why I didn't mention it. +++ You can write a class caching and recalculating three things: `allEmployees`, `employeeAvg`, and `employeeEff`.

Comment: As much as I want to write my own class that caches all the things I need, I would rather NOT re-invent the wheel lol. I'll probably stick with the Guava cache

Comment: @MiguelPortugal Do whatever suits you best. Rerinventing the whole `Cache` would be a major task, but all you need is a tiny part. See my update.