# Java 7: best way to implement thread-safe modifiable static object in ServletContextListener?

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets, concurrency

In a Java 7 Tomcat application, an object/structure *obj* containing several simple (String and numeric) types is frequently shared (read) by multiple servlet threads. Periodically (every n minutes), all of *obj*'s members need to be refreshed simultaneously and atomically with respect to each other, and each of the servlet threads must always get the updated values whenever it reads the object. If no clients are connected, there is no need to refresh the values; but as soon as one does connect (assuming at least n minutes have passed since the last update), the update needs to happen **before** the object is read. **Update:** I should mention that currently, one of *obj*'s members is a timestamp indicating when the object data expires and needs to be refreshed. If a solution, such as Guava Cache suggested in a comment below, already has this functionality built in, then all the better.

How would you implement this in Java 7? At this point, simplicity and 'cleanliness' are more important than performance, but if you also want to provide a solution that's optimized for performance, please do. I have an idea that may or may not work the way I expect, but would like to hear other opinions first. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about app deployed in cluster. Do you still want to share that state in between app instances running on different VM?

Comment: @tsolakp Good question! Now that I think about it, I probably do.

Comment: Then you probably will need some type of distributed cache like Ehcache or Hazelcast.

Comment: And what about availability? Should the data remain available after a JVM crash? (The solution would still be an external cache, but one that is itself [configured to be] distributed and usually [configured to] have persistence in a reliable data store)

Comment: I would use Guava Cache. Create the object in the servlet context listener and then you can access/modify it anywhere in the application.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt No, it will be refreshed when the server starts again; the data itself is not that 'valuable' - it can be refreshed at any time, and the new values can be used thereafter. Honestly, I think an external cache might be overkill for storing a couple of strings, but it's good to hear different ideas.

Comment: @stepanian Guava Cache might actually be just what I need. I didn't mention this in the question, but probably should have: one of the object members is a timestamp that indicates when it needs to be refreshed; looks like Guava Cache has this capability already built-in, which would be perfect.

Comment: Guava caches are not distributed though.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen True. I guess the idea of an external cache sounded good for a second, but then I realized how much overhead that would require and changed my mind :) On further thought, sharing the data between apps/vm's is not necessary.

Comment: OK, in that case I'd also go for a Guava cache like others in this thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) Cache.

In the context listener, do something like this:

```
LoadingCache<String, List<YourObjectType>> myCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
    .expireAfterWrite(60, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    .build(new CacheLoader<String, List<YourObjecttype>>() {
        public List<YourObjectType> load(String arg) {
            ...
        }
});
```

Save it to your servlet context:

```
ServletContext servletContext = servletContextEvent.getServletContext();
servletContext.setAttribute("myCache", myCache);
```

Then use it anywhere by getting the "myCache" attribute from the context object.

Comment: Let me know if you need additional code for example on how to refresh it and/or how to use it from a servlet.

Comment: Yes, that would be great. I can see that

`expireAfterWrite(60, TimeUnit.MINUTES)`

will cause the cache to expire after an hour, but how do I make it automatically call my custom refresh code upon expiration? Does `load` get called every time something is `put` into the cache?

Comment: Let me clarify: I don't necessarily want the cache to be refreshed immediately after expiring; I need it to refresh prior to the next read, which I think is the default behavior. But how do I specify/override the refresh behavior so that it will call my code to generate the new values to put into the cache?

Comment: ^ default behavior when using `refreshAfterWrite(...)`.

Comment: #refreshAfterWrite() calls the #reload method, which you can provide in the #build method: http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/CacheLoader.html#reload-K-V-

Comment: I'm confused. So, let's say I have 2 methods: `getInitialValues()` and `getUpdatedValues()`, which do some relatively 'heavy' stuff to get the values that will go into the cache. I can call `getInitialValues()` on startup and have it return eg a HashMap, which I can then pass to `cache.putAll(map)` - my understanding is that this call would be an atomic operation, right? But then, how/where do I call `getUpdatedValues()` when I need to refresh the cache? I can override  `CacheLoader.reload()`, but that method is called for every key. How can I call it once and ensure an atomic refresh?

Comment: ^ Basically the same question as: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31576136/how-should-i-implement-guava-cache-when-i-plan-to-cache-multiple-values-efficien

Comment: Thought about it some more, and the solution might be to use a single 'dummy' key, with the value being a composite object containing all the data that needs to be updated on refresh. I looked at guava Suppliers, but the functionality is too castrated for my needs. Found a discussion on Guava's github where multiple people requested exactly what I need: a keyless cache for a single object/value. I guess they haven't implemented it, so your solution may be the only thing that works for me :)

Comment: @Yury Make sure you accept my answer if it was useful to you :)

Comment: Just did. Looks like I have everything working now, although it took me a while to figure it out, not having worked with any of this stuff before :)